# Pyspark : how to compute the percentage with condition in dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

How to compute the number of performance such that performance = P<=5 ; P>5 & P<=15 ; P>15

| address | performance = P |
| --- | --- |
| NACELLES | 589 |
| NACELLES | 0 |
| NACELLES | 48 |
| NACELLES | 318 |
| NACELLES | 378 |
| NACELLES | 52 |
| NACELLES | 45 |
| NACELLES | 201 |
| NACELLES | 416 |
| NACELLES | 29 |
| NACELLES | 183 |
| NACELLES | 53 |
| NACELLES | 7 |
| NACELLES | 127 |
| NACELLES | 157 |
| NACELLES | 248 |
| NACELLES | 10 |
| NACELLES | 317 |
| NACELLES | 2 |
| NACELLES | 4 |

We obtain this dataset

| address | P<=5 | P>5 & P<=15 | P> 15 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NACELLES | 15 % | 10 % | 75 % |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using your dataframe as an example :

```py
+--------+-----------+                                                          
| address|performance|
+--------+-----------+
|NACELLES|        589|
|NACELLES|          0|
|NACELLES|         48|
|NACELLES|        318|
```

You simply have to aggregate and sum using a when function :

```py
df.groupBy("address").agg(
    (F.sum(F.when(F.col("performance") <= 5, 1)) / F.count("*")).alias("P<=5"),
    (
        F.sum(F.when((F.col("performance") > 5) & (F.col("performance") <= 15), 1))
        / F.count("*")
    ).alias("P>5 & P<=15"),
    (F.sum(F.when(F.col("performance") > 15, 1)) / F.count("*")).alias("P>15"),
).show()

+--------+----+-----------+----+
| address|P<=5|P>5 & P<=15|P>15|
+--------+----+-----------+----+
|NACELLES|0.15|        0.1|0.75|
+--------+----+-----------+----+
```